# I am trying to show DatePicker in InputView while click on TextField

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, uidatepicker, unwrap

When ever I try this code it show an error

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)
```

I have tried many solution, watched many success videos but when I am trying in my code it shows the above error

```
import Foundation
import UIKit



class MainNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    @IBOutlet weak var IfFromDate: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var IfToDate: UITextField!
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showDatePicker()


    }

    func showDatePicker(){
        //Formate Date

        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        IfFromDate.inputView = datePicker //accruing error on this line

    }
    @IBAction func btnSignIn(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use UINavigationController. Use UIViewController

Comment: IFFromDate is not found in UINavigationController. It should be in UIViewController and you have to also make sure that your outlet is connected.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR yes working on UIViewController but I want to do this UINavigationController, is there any way to the same in Nav controller?

Comment: You can add view controller on top of that and display date picker there

Comment: @SatyenChauhan yes I have double checked my outlet (IfFromdate) is connected to UINavigationController

Comment: @AhmadHayyat don't use with UINavigationController. I don't know what you trying to achieve but you can add viewController in storyboard then you can embed it into navigation controller.

Comment: @AhmadHayyat Why do you want to add the textfields in a navigation controller rather than viewcontroller ?